# Winfor vs WPF vs WinRTmarketshare

Tags: asp.net, wpf, winforms, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

Having experience in java (awt and swing) and also in html and javascript I have moved and in my new country found a job in a consulting company as a developer.
I also had experience doing some stuff in c#, but never touched the GUI part.
I have seen that the most of our clients are using .net, so I have decided to update my knowledge in .net and also learn about the GUIs while I have no assigned client.

But my problem is that for the GUI part I can see there is:

- Windows forms
- Windows Presentation Foundation(WPF)
- WinRT
- Universal Windows Platform (UWP)
- asp.net

I understand all of those are not the same, some are compatible with each other (winform and WPF) and others are not. Syntaxis is different and also the elements available to create the GUI. I have searched and even coded some basic examples and found out even the way to program (events vs databinding) changes a lot. I also read several discussions about the pros and cons for each one.

Now, taking into account my context (big company, not a startup) which one of the above technologies should I focus into? and by this I mean: **Which one has a bigger marketshare in 2016 or will have more action in the near future** (I know it's impossibe to predict technology in 10 years but lets say 2-3 years). Is there any statistics or any official position from Microsoft about wich one will be the standard?

Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Edit: For those who didn't understand and are down voting my question saying is opinion based: I am not asking for which one you prefer. I am asking is there's some statistics or an official position from Microsoft about this.
Some of you say you cannot compare different technologies because it is like to compare programming languages. This has been done, because I am not asking to compare the technology itself but the marketshare. If you want to compare javascript with .net and abap MARKETSHARE you can use the tiobe index.

If you dont know the answer simply do not say anything, but not pretend people cannot ask things you don't know about.

Edit2: Finally I found what I was looking for.
For desktop application 
42% use Windows Forms, 46% WPF and 8% UWP
More data available at http://www.telerik.com/campaigns/devcraft/net-developer-report-for-2016

Comment: Voting to close as this is not a programming specific question and thus does not fit in here.

Comment: Why the voting to close? Sorry I am new here. Only questions with code sample are allowed? My question is not about opinions or open questions. I am asking about facts, and where to get them.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. Use ASP.NET if you're building a website or webapp, use WPF if you have to support pre-windows 10 operating systems, or use UWP if you only plan on supporting windows 10. You can skip WinForms and WinRT tbh.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: javascript, java, matlab and cobol are also 3 different things, used for different purposes. Nevertheless you can go to [this link](http://www.tiobe.com/tiobe_index) and find the marketshare for those languages.
I am not asking which one you prefer or which one is better. I am asking about which one is more used, I am asking for numbers and numbers can be compared.

Comment: @dour-high-arch, mike-mccaughan,nikhilvartak, PanagiotisKanavos ,Clemens and: hichris123 I already found my answer and included it in the edition.
Thank you for being so supportive and down vote my question only because you didn't know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

WinForms is very old technology, so better choose something new.

If talk about vacancies now, I think that ASP.Net is leader. What would be in future - have no idea. Azure? ASP.Net Core?

WinRT (Windows Store 8.1 Apps) and UWP are have much in common but not extermely popular yet. Advantage is that you can write your apps already for desktop, phone, XBox, raspberry pi and more devices.
WinRT Windows 8 Apps are depricated.

WPF is nice. Better start learn .Net Core Apps (they are crossplatform)

Xamarin crossplatform apps are also popular now. You can write C# apps for Windows, iOs and Android.